# Confusing Cordova icons and splash screens directory

Tags: android, cordova, icons, splash-screen

The [Cordova docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens), regarding the use of icons and splash screens for Android, states that they should be placed in ***[www/res/icons](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens_configuring_icons_in_the_cli)*** and ***www/res/screens*** directories respectively.. But afterwards, in the same page, it says;

> you'll need to copy the png files from
>   ***platforms/android/www/res/screen/android*** to
>   ***platforms/android/res/drawable*/***

So; if the icons and splash screens should be copied to to the drawable folder, what is the use of having them on ***www/res/icons**** and ***www/res/screens***

This is confusing (@_@) Especially when the docs add more ambiguity;

```
 ..When working in the CLI...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some researches and trial/error I got it fixed and wrote a tutorial about my process;

[Cordova Icons and Splash Screens](http://www.numediaweb.com/cordova-icons-splash-screens/)

Hope it helps somebody else :)

Comment: link is dead --filler--

Answer (score 1):

When working in the CLI means if you are building with the Command-Line Interface of Cordova/PhoneGap and does not apply if you say are using PhoneGap Build (http://build.phonegap.com) to build for you. Which version are you working on?

Comment: Thanks, This clarifies half second half of the problem. I'm using cordova with CLI along with Yeoman (Grunt, Bower) all latest versions. I have prepared my app icons and screens as stated in the Docs but cordova just ignors them.

Comment: Have you added the Splashscreen plugin in Cordova as per: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html#Splashscreen

In my experience the splashscreen is only automatically shown in iOS, in Android I believe it defaults to nothing unless you specify to show splashscreen

Comment: I'll do that. But what is the use of having them on www/res/icons* and www/res/screens? Doesn't cordova build takes care of deploying those assets to the platform automatically?

Comment: Now I'm not an expert on the CLI as I usually use PhoneGap Build, but I believe you put icons in icons and splashscreens in screens - and that these are then deployed when you "build" with cordova to the respective platforms.